# I am trying to add the close function

Tags: javascript, html, code-snippets

I have created an email subscription form at site footer. But the problem is, when i click the close icon, the form do not disappears.

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#close");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var t = document.querySelector(div.getAttribute("data-target"));
  t.style.display = "none" == t.style.display ? "block" : "none"
});
```

```html
<div class="hook-section js-common-hook">
  <div class="hook-content small-hook-show">
    <div class="loader">
      Loading...
    </div>
    <div class="hook-close-btn sprite-img">Close</div>
    <div class="top-sec clearfix">
      <div class="left-sec sprite-img">
      </div>
      <div class="right-sec">
        <h5>Email Newsletter</h5>
        <p>The best of technology updates from India and around the world</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bootom-sec">
      <form class="hook-form" action='https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=TechLekhak' method='post' onsubmit='window.open
    (&apos;https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=12c55&apos;,
     &apos;popupwindow&apos;, &apos;scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520&apos;);return true' target='popupwindow'>
        <input placeholder="Enter your email id" name="email" type="text" />
        <input value="12c55" name="uri" type="hidden" />
        <input value="en_US" name="loc" type="hidden" /><button class="subs-btn">Subscribe Now</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what `document.querySelector(div.getAttribute
("data-target"));` is referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You are matching the wrong thing with your query selector. 
You are trying to get an element with a "close" id but you have none in your code.

This could be arranged by adding `id="close"` to thr tag you want to trigger the click function you defined

Example :

```
<div id="close" class="hook-close-btn sprite-img">Close</div>
```

Same is happening to the queryselector that matches the item you want to close... It doesn't exist and you will need to adjust it

You can change the `id="toggle"` around the page to see that those elements are the ones that get open and closed

Here is a snippet

```js
var toggler = document.querySelector("#close");
toggler.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var toggleElement = document.querySelector("#toggle");
  if (!toggleElement.style.display || toggleElement.style.display === "block") {
    toggleElement.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    toggleElement.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="hook-section js-common-hook">
  <div class="hook-content small-hook-show">
    <button id="close" class="hook-close-btn sprite-img">Close</button>
    <div class="top-sec clearfix">
      <div class="left-sec sprite-img">
      </div>
      <div class="right-sec">
        <h5>Email Newsletter</h5>
        <p>The best of technology updates from India and around the world</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bootom-sec">
      <form id="toggle" class="hook-form" action='https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=TechLekhak' method='post' onsubmit='window.open
    (&apos;https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=12c55&apos;,
     &apos;popupwindow&apos;, &apos;scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520&apos;);return true' target='popupwindow'>
        <input placeholder="Enter your email id" name="email" type="text" />
        <input value="12c55" name="uri" type="hidden" />
        <input value="en_US" name="loc" type="hidden" /><button class="subs-btn">Subscribe Now</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, link a snippet in codepen or something similar, dont link to a post or a site that could very well be just spam, not that you are doing spam but it might be considered

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. i removed the comment containing a site link.

Comment: @FarooqAhmadBhat It's Ok, I understood that it happened by mistake or similar, just wanted to give you a heads up :) just in case ( I assumed you were quite new so don't worry) Anyhow, I've updated the answer, and it should give you a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

what element are you targeting with this?

```
var t = document.querySelector(div.getAttribute("data-target"));
```

Your code should be:

```
<div id="popup" class="hook-section js-common-hook">    //your box

<div id="close" class="hook-close-btn sprite-img">Close</div>      // your button
```

then:

```
var button = document.querySelector("#close");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var t = document.querySelector("#popup"));
  t.style.display = "none";
});
```

Basically you need to fix your elements' names.
Let me know if it works :)